# Unknown USB Flash Drive

Tags: partitioning, usb

Suddenly my Kingston DataTraveler 8GB is shown as unknown! The weird thing is that I can only "see" it through `Disk Utility`.

`GParted` or `sudo fdisk -l` or `sudo fdisk -lu` cannot see it.

I tried to format the entire drive as Master Boot record but I get an error saying

```
Error creating partition table: helper exited with exit code 1: In 
part_create_partition_table: device_file=/dev/sdc, scheme=0
ped_device_get() failed
```

the only way to be formatted is to select `Don't Partition`. If I then try to partition the volume in ext4 I get the error

```
Error creating file system: helper exited with exit code 1: helper failed with:
mke2fs 1.41.11 (14-Mar-2010)
mkfs.ext4: Device size reported to be zero.  Invalid partition specified, or
partition table wasn't reread after running fdisk, due to
a modified partition being busy and in use.  You may need to reboot
to re-read your partition table.
```

If I try to format the volume in NTFS I get the error

```
Error creating file system: helper exited with exit code 1: helper failed with:
/dev/sdc is entire device, not just one partition.
Refusing to make a filesystem here!
```

If I select `Empty` nothing happens, but it is still registered as unknown.

any ideas on how to fix it? I don't really care about the data;I just need my USB flash back!

Comment: try to unmount it first before doing anything. Hope it will do.

Comment: I suspect that your USB drive is terminally broken. Can you perform the basic check of [How do I check the integrity of a storage medium?](/a/539185/175814) and report its result?

Answer (score 1):

First make sure your formatting the data partition/drive. Some USB sticks have gone the way of putting two devices on one chip so they can include their garbage.

Next make sure your device is in read write mode (there may be a physical switch on the device)

Finally re-partition (don't format) using fdisk it should be something like `sudo fdisk /dev/sdb`

And, if that doesn't work your can always try forcing it to wipe the drive with something like (as root) `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdb` **Careful with that though** it will destroy anything on the drive you specify without mercy or chance of recovery.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! It doesn't have any physical switch and as far as if there are two devices in it, I can't tell. What I can tell though is that, I cannot excecute `dd` because I am not able to see the USB drive when I use `sudo fdisk -l`. The only way to see the drive is through Disk Utility.

Comment: when you plug in the drive be running `tail -f /var/log/messages` it should give you a device name or list an error.